# What happened in this simple function call stack?

Tags: c, memory-management, gdb, stack, function-call

Suppose we have the following super simple prorgam `ex.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getpath()
{
  char buffer[8];
  gets(buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  getpath();
}
```

What I would expect to see in the stack just before returning to the main() function would be something like

```
buffer[0-3]
buffer[4-7]
SAVED_EBP
SAVED_EIP
```

Instead between the `SAVED_EBP` and `buffer` there are ALWAYS two weird addresses `xb7ec6300` and `0xb7ff1040` (see gdb() session below), I tried with different buffer lengths since I thought that it was something due to some kind of padding done by the compiler, however, they're always there.
My question is? What are these addresses and why are they always allocated?

---

`getpath()` assembly:

```
(gdb) disass getpath
Dump of assembler code for function getpath:
0x080483c4 <getpath+0>:     push   ebp
0x080483c5 <getpath+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
0x080483c7 <getpath+3>:     sub    esp,0x28
0x080483ca <getpath+6>:     lea    eax,[ebp-0x10]
0x080483cd <getpath+9>:     mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x080483d0 <getpath+12>:    call   0x80482e8 <gets@plt>
0x080483d5 <getpath+17>:    leave  
0x080483d6 <getpath+18>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

After compiling (`gcc -o ex ex.c`) , setting a breakpoint at `getpath`'s `leave` instruction, and feeding `AAAAAAA` as input:

```
(gdb) x/12x $sp
0xbffffc80: 0xbffffc98  0x0804959c  0xbffffcb8  0x08048419
0xbffffc90: 0xb7fd8304  0xb7fd7ff4  0x41414141  0x00414141
0xbffffca0: 0xb7ec6365  0xb7ff1040  0xbffffcb8  0x080483e2

(gdb) x/1x 0xb7ec6365
0xb7ec6365 <__cxa_atexit+53>:   0x5b10c483

(gdb) x/1x 0xb7ff1040
0xb7ff1040 <_dl_fini>:  0x57e58955

(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xbffffcb0:
 eip = 0x80483d5 in getpath; saved eip 0x80483e2
 called by frame at 0xbffffcc0
 Arglist at 0xbffffca8, args: 
 Locals at 0xbffffca8, Previous frame's sp is 0xbffffcb0
 Saved registers:
  ebp at 0xbffffca8, eip at 0xbffffcac
```

### Update

Thanks @Daniel Kleinstein! So apparently the responsable is `gets()` as we can see here:

I wrote two trivial programs whose only difference is the use of `gets()`:

- `gets.c`:

  ```c
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  char getpath()
  {
    char buffer[4];
    gets(buffer);
  }

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
    getpath();
  }
  ```
- `nogets.c`

  ```c
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  void getpath()
  {
    char buffer[4] = {65,65,65,65};
  }

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
    getpath();
  }
  ```

Then we run the two programs with `gdb` and set a `breakpoint` in correpondence of the `leave` instruction in `getpath` (as we did before), we check the stack with the command `x/12x $sp`.

- `gets.c STACK FRAME`
  [image: gets.c stack frame]
  As you can see `0xb7ec6365` and `0xb7ff1040` are still there.
- `nogets.c STACK FRAME`
  [image: nogets.c stack frame]

But I can't find any documentation about this cleanup procedure, do you have any idea on how could I dig deeper?

Comment: The call convection may contain a reserved area for saving additional, callee saved registers. Common optimization as this way ESP only needs to be incremented once for small functions, instead of the called function also having to do so.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by "this way ESP only needs to be incremented once for small functions, instead of the called function also having to do so". I tried to compile the same code with no optimization allowed (`-O0` flag) but the stack frame is always the same, so is this still the case?

Comment: It means this is part of the call convention. The callee is guaranteed that the caller has reserved some space, and may use it without second guessing.

Don't confuse compiler optimizations (you are thinking about in-lining) with optimizations in the design of the interface (which applies to non-in-lined function calls only).

Comment: @Ext3h This isn't calling conventions - it has to do with `gets` cleanup. If you replace `gets` with calls to other `glibc` functions you won't get the same effects. (And indeed, no calling convention specifies that you must place `atexit` or `_dl_fini` on the stack)

Comment: Thanks, @DanielKleinstein! You were right (I updated the question and proved your point), do you have any idea where could I find some documentation on that?  How did you know that?

Comment: @ИванКарамазов  This doesn't seem to be well-documented behavior. If you look at `gets`'s implementation [here](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/595c22ecd8e87a27fd19270ed30fdbae9ad25426/libio/iogets.c#L37) then you can see a call to `_IO_acquire_lock` - which uses gcc's `__attribute__(cleanup`, which I _think_ is what is causing this stack manipulation - but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll stop digging into it then

Comment: In the version of your program that calls gets, can you do `awatch -l *0xbffffca0` and then run the program, then see which functions write to that location? Since  getpath allocates 0x28 bytes in its stack frame and doesn't access most of those bytes, the mysterious addresses you see may have been written by a previously-called function.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that it was something due to some kind of padding done by the compiler,

They are in fact just padding added by the compiler to keep stack 32-byte aligned. You can get rid of them with `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2`.